# Input submit wanting to change on hover with css

Tags: css, button

http://jsfiddle.net/4UA82/1/

```
    #subscribe-submit input[type="submit"] {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    padding-top: 5px !important;
    padding-right: 5px !important;
    padding-bottom: 5px !important;
    padding-left: 5px !important;
    background-color: #24890d !important;
}
#subscribe-submit input[type="submit"]:visited {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
}
#subscribe-submit input[type="submit"]:hover {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    color: #000000 !important;
}
#subscribe-submit input[type="submit"]:active {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
}
```

I am just trying to get this button to hover to the desired background color, but it is not working for some reason.

I can get it to hover if I delete the initial settings though:

```
  #subscribe-submit input[type="submit"] {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    padding-top: 5px !important;
    padding-right: 5px !important;
    padding-bottom: 5px !important;
    padding-left: 5px !important;
    background-color: #24890d !important;
}
```

So I am not sure what is going on.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `!important` tag

```
#subscribe-submit input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #24890d;
}
```

The need to use `!important` on every attribute suggests that there are flaws in the way you are structuring your CSS

Comment: In fact remove all `!important` statements...you're massively overusing them.

Comment: thanks! I used this button css gernerator plugin and it puts the !important tags in automatically. I didn't think they could cause issues

Answer (score 0):

In #subscribe-submit input[type="submit"]  Change

```
background-color: #24890d!important;
```

to

```
 background-color: #24890d;
```